# Create PopUp Window in Java

Tags: java, winforms, window

How would I make a pop up box/A dialog window  in Java? For instance say I want to make a window saying "Hello My name is John Smith". How would I do that? Would I have to use swing?

Comment: [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP would be better served reading an appropriate tutorial, like [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: *"Would I have to use swing?"* - Why?  Don't you want to?

Comment: Question closed as a duplicate and my answer was made a community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use Swing by simply using a Swing `javax.swing.JOptionPane`.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialg(null, "hello world");
```

Comment: you need to import javax.swing.JOptionPanel; then   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Object message");